# How to divide a triangle in 3 equal parts from altitude to hypotenuse?

Tags: triangles, area

How can I divide a right angled triangle into 3 equal parts having equal areas using lines parallel to base from altitude to hypotenuse? Actually this is a piece of land and we want it to divide in such a way that.

```
 Area of a = Area of b = Area of c
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See that when you would try to divide your triangle using lines parallel to the base , you will get three similar triangles.

Using the fact that for two similar triangles if their sides are in the ratio $\frac{p}{q} \ $
the areas are in ratio $\frac{p^2}{q^2}$.

Here since the areas a and a+b are in ratio $\frac{1}{2}\ $, it means that the sides would be in ratio $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ $,
similarly sides of a and a+b+c would be in ratio $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \ $.

which means you need to divide your altitude into three segments in ratio $1:\sqrt{2}-1:\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: How do we get three similar triangles? I didn't get this.

Comment: as the lines going from altitude to the hypotenuse are parallel to each other, the triangles are similar. Use the fact that all triangles have one common angle and other two angles are formed by the same transversal line intersecing the parallel lines